# MATLAB: polyval function for N greater than 1

Tags: matlab, regression

I am trying trying to graph the polynomial fit of a 2D dataset in Matlab.

This is what I tried:

```
rawTable = readtable('Test_data.xlsx','Sheet','Sheet1');
x = rawTable.A;
y = rawTable.B;
figure(1)
scatter(x,y)
c = polyfit(x,y,2);
y_fitted = polyval(c,x);
hold on
plot(x,y_fitted,'r','LineWidth',2)
```

`rawTable.A` and `rawTable.A` are randomly generated numbers. (i.e. the x dataset cannot be represented in the following form : `x=0:0.1:100`)

The result:

[second-order polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmmTg.png)

But the result I expect looks like this (generated in Excel):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukoy5.png)

How can I graph the second-order polynomial fit in MATLAB?

Comment: Are you doing this in excel?

Comment: Hi! Have you looked at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Do take a look! The ideas in these pages are essential in communicating your problems to the rest of the community. In your specific case, you should provide sample data and better definition of what comprises of your data. You need to explain the expected behavior and how what you get is unexpected.

Comment: The data are in excel format. I have used MATLAB to extract the data from the excel sheet and trying to plot the second-order best fit line through the points. However, the plot, as observed, comprises of multiple graphs.

Comment: Further, what does your question  "How can i graph a single line for N (order) = 2 and above" mean?  That goes again to explaining what the expected behavior is: what is the "line"? Is it the polynomial fit of a 2D data set? Is it the spline of some data set? Is it just the graph of a function of known analytical form? Is it a *straight* line as "line" usually means? etc etc etc. One cannot tell whether your problem is understanding `polyfit` or understanding plotting in Matlab or just running into some syntax glitch. And that's what a question should complete in explaining.

Comment: @Yuv: Please do examine my comment. You should explain what you do not expect in the body your question. The most likely situation is that you are mistaking the figure for the graphs of multiple functions because your data set is not sorted. You are not helping yourself by getting everyone else to guess something they shouldn't have to. You need to be more precise.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience caused @Argyll. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Yuv: I'll make some minor but important edits to make the terminology clean. Please take a look. If you agree with them, you should probably use clean terminology yourself too. If you don't, please roll back the edits.

Comment: @Yuv: As well, if you replace `x`, `y` with `rand(1,100)` for example, does it convey the same question?

Comment: Yes, i do agree with the edited one. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it does convey the same question.

Comment: @Yuv: I see. I think I understand your question now. I can write an answer. Now, using simple `x` and `y` here is to give a *minimal example*. (Please see link earlier.) Anyone can use `rand(1,100)` and try your code themselves and therefore understand the problem you are running into. Of course, in this case, you need to convey the idea that `x` and `y` are likely correlated. For example, your *minimal example* can be `y=(x+randn(1,100)).^2+x+1+randn(1,100)`. And you want to specify the kind of `x` and `y` you have in mind.

Comment: @Yuv: These will be important for successfully getting answers in your future questions.

Comment: @Argyll I have not understood your question.

Comment: @Yuv: Which part? About minimal example or about conveying the idea of correlation or about the use of `randn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense some confusion regarding what the output of each of those Matlab function mean. So I'll clarify. And I think we need some details as well. So expect some verbosity. A quick answer, however, is available at the end.

`c = polyfit(x,y,2)` gives the coefficient vectors of the polynomial fit. You can get the fit information such as error estimate following the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).

Name this polynomial as P. P in Matlab is actually the function `P=@(x)c(1)*x.^2+c(2)*x+c(3)`.

Suppose you have a *single point* `X`, then `polyval(c,X)` outputs the value of `P(X)`. And if `x` is a vector, `polyval(c,x)` is a vector corresponding to `[P(x(1)), P(x(2)),...]`.

Now that does **not** represent what the fit is. Just as a quick hack to see something visually, you can try `plot(sort(x),polyval(c,sort(x)),'r','LineWidth',2)`, ie. you can first sort your data and *try* plotting on those x-values.

However, it is only a hack because a) your data set may be so irregularly spaced that the spline doesn't represent function or b) evaluating on the whole of your data set is unnecessary and inefficient.

The robust and 'standard' way to plot a 2D function of known analytical form in Matlab is as follows:

1. Define some *evenly-spaced* x-values over the interval you want to plot the function. For example, `x=1:0.1:10`. For example, `x=linspace(0,1,100)`.
2. Evaluate the function on these x-values
3. Put the above two components into `plot()`. `plot()` can either plot the function as sampled points, or connect the points with automatic [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation), which is the default.

(For step 1, **quadrature** is ambiguous but specific enough of a term to describe this process if you wish to communicate with a single word.)

So, instead of using the `x` in your original data set, you should do something like:

```
t=linspace(min(x),max(x),100);
plot(t,polyval(c,t),'r','LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. @Argyll You are a life saviour.

Comment: @Yuv: Hope that answers your question.